# Summa question on his quotation of scripture

Tags: summa-theologica

Been reading the Summa and ran across a verse, or maybe translation, that I couldn’t match up.  Aquinas quotes Psalm 11:2 several times and I thought it was a typo but I can’t find the text in any version any where in scripture.  Could someone elucidate why?

SUMMA THEOLOGICA
First Part (Prima Pars)
Question 16. Truth

[SIXTH ARTICLE [I, Q. 16, Art. 6] Whether There Is Only One Truth, According to Which All Things Are True?](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP016.html#FPQ16A6THEP1)

Psalm 11: 2, "Truths are decayed from among the children of men," says: "As from one man's face many likenesses are reflected in a mirror, so many truths are reflected from the one divine truth."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The older Latin Vulgate Bible, whose 1592 edition [became the official Bible of the Church](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgate) was already by the time of Aquinas the unofficial standard, and it appears this was the translation he used.

As a note on the numbering, Psalm 10 is an acrostic - the verses begin with consecutive letters of the Hebrew alphabet. The Vulgate counted this as one psalm from first to last letter of the alphabet; other translations from the Hebrew, including the New Vulgate, broke it into two before the verse beginning with *lamedh* and numbered the second half as Psalm 11,making the psalm in question Psalm 12.

The passage in the older Vulgate, which would have been that available to Aquinas, runs

> Salvum me fac, Domine, quoniam defecit sanctus,
>   quoniam diminutæ sunt veritates a filiis hominum.

My translation might be

> Make me safe [i.e. "Save me"], Lord, for there is no holy one; for truths have been worn down from [perhaps "from among"] the children of men

which is very nearly the quote referenced from the Douay-Rheims Bible and excerpted in your question. The Nova Vulgata, which is the current official Latin version retranslated from Hebrew and Greek, words the passage almost identically, substituting *fideles*  "faithful/the faithful ones" for *veritates* "truths".

Looking at the Hebrew original, it appears that Jerome translated the Hebrew word אֱ֝מוּנִ֗ים, an adjective, as a noun. Thus instead of "the faithful/loyal/true ones", he gets "the truths".

It appears then that Aquinas' quote doesn't mean exactly what he thinks it does - though his conclusion is still reasonable.

Comment: In essence you are saying this is a old translation of what is now often regarded as the second half of Psalms 12:1

Comment: Not quite. An old translation of the psalm following what's now regarded as the second half of Psalm 10.

Answer (score 0):

The [Douay-Rheims translation of Psalm 11:2](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=11&l=2#x)b reads

> …truths are decayed from among the children of men.

or the Vulgate:

> …diminutae sunt veritates a filiis hominum.

which St. Thomas quotes verbatim.

The corresponding verse in the book of Psalms in Moseretic-numbered bibles would be 12:2.

Comment: So the answer is the Summa English version is a translation from the Latin?  The Hebrew still doesn’t look anything like 11:2 or 12:2

Comment: @Tonyg: Try the second half of Psalms 12:1